Run Flask app in a sub-directory with error log and WSGI Process Group
I try to migrate a Flask app from an Ubuntu 22.04 server (originally it is configured as a Virtual Host) to RHEL 9.4 server (as a sub-directory script), both running Apache web server and having WSGI module installed. From this question, I know that I can set the WSCGIScriptAlias to configure the sub-directory. But my question is, how can I convert a VirtualHost to a sub-directory script?
The configuration in Ubuntu (/etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.example.com.conf):
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/www/path/to/flask/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName  subdomain.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/flask

        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/path/to/flask/flaskapp.wsgi
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        <Directory flaskapp>
             WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
             WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
             Order deny,allow
             Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flask-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flask-access.log combined
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

and here is the RHEL Apache config (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf):
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted

    # Flask app related
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /subfolder /var/www/path/to/flask/flaskapp.wsgi
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Directory>

How can I set the ErrorLog, CustomLog, WSGIProcessGroup, WSGIApplicationGroup and the WSGIPythonPath (for the virtual environment)?
Please help, thanks.
